# Normalize composite/decomposable/variable-length characters (unicode/python3.4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, unicode, python-unicode, unicode-normalization

I stumbled upon http://mortoray.com/2013/11/27/the-string-type-is-broken/

And to my horror...

```
print(len('noe\u0308l')) # returns 5 not 4
```

However I found
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14682498/1267259, 
[Normalizing Unicode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode)

```
from unicodedata import normalize
print(len(unicodedata.normalize('NFC','noe\u0308l'))) # returns 4
```

But what do I do with the Schrödinger's cats?

```
print(len('')) # returns 4 not 2
```

(side question: in my text editor when I'm trying to save I get a "utf-8 codec can't encode character x in position y: surrogates not allowed" but in the command prompt I can paste and run code with those characters, I assume it is because the cats exist on a different quantum level (SMP) but how do I normalize them?)

Is there anything else I should do to make sure all characters are counted as "1"?

Comment: Which specific version of Python 3? Unicode processing has undergone a change or two.

Comment: I'm using python 3.4.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your editor is producing [surrogate pairs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-16#U.2B10000_to_U.2B10FFFF), not the actual code points, which is why you are also getting that warning. Use:

```
'\U0001f638\U0001f63e'
```

to define the cats without resorting to surrogates.

If you do have a string with surrogates, you can recode these via UTF-16 and allowing surrogates to be encoded with the `'surrogatepass'` error handler:

```
>>> # \U0001f638 is \ud83d\ude38 when using UTF-16 surrogates
...
>>> '\ud83d\ude38'.encode('utf16', 'surrogatepass').decode('utf16')
''
>>> len(_)
1
```

From the [*Error Handlers* documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#error-handlers):

> `'surrogateescape'`
>   On decoding, replace byte with individual surrogate code ranging from `U+DC80` to `U+DCFF`. This code will then be turned back into the same byte when the `'surrogateescape'` error handler is used when encoding the data. (See [PEP 383](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0383/) for more.)

Comment: In hindsight, that was so obvious. I'm leaving my answer up in case it's useful to a passerby later.

Comment: Thanks, that did take care of the error message, unfortunately no more cute cats... Although `len('\U0001f638\U0001f63e')` returns 2 now. But how do I ensure that actual code points are always used or surrogate pairs are never used? Do I need to "normalize" the string somehow? Do I have to do as Mark R suggested?

Comment: @user1267259: what is your *normal* source of data input? If they are string literals in the source, I'd use `\Uhhhhhhhh` escape sequences, as it saves a lot of headaches with editors and encoding configurations. When reading from a file or network connection, use the right codec, you should not normally end up with surrogates in your Unicode string values, only in the encoded bytes (where they belong).

Comment: Ahh, I see. My normal source are a bunch of text files. I've striped out non-Latin characters but had a feeling composite characters could cause problems so I googled until I found mentioned article. The variable-length characters were new to me, and in my panic I assumed they too could be considered "decomposed" somehow (given the result of the length). It didn't help that I copied and pasted those cats :) But if I understand you: as long as I load/encode those files correct there shouldn't be any problems with surrogates. I only need to unicodedata.normalize (sorry if I'm being redundant).

Answer (score 0):

For consistent codepoint counting on *any* version of Python, encode to UTF-32 and divide the byte count by 4.

```
print(len(unicodedata.normalize('NFC','noe\u0308l').encode('utf-32le')) / 4)
print(len('\U0001f638\U0001f63e'.encode('utf-32le')) / 4)
```

Comment: But the OP is using Python 3.4. This is not a polyglot issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that information wasn't added until I left my answer. If you have a better one, go for it, because at this point I'm mystified.