# Remove unicode characters python

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, unicode-string

I am pulling tweets in python using tweepy.
It gives the entire data in type unicode.
Eg: print type(data) gives me `<type 'unicode'>`

It contains unicode characters in it.
Eg: `hello\u2026 im am fine\u2019s`

I want to remove all of these unicode characters. Is there any regular expression i can use?
`str.replace` isn't a viable option as unicode characters can be any values, from smileys to unicode apostrophes.

Comment: All text is Unicode. Do you mean *non-ASCII characters* perhaps?

Comment: Yes non ascii characters. It's normal text in english interspersed with \u2026 etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
In [10]: from unicodedata import normalize

In [11]: out_text = normalize('NFKD', input_text).encode('ascii','ignore')
```

Try this.

**Edit**

Actually normalize Return the normal form form for the Unicode string unistr. Valid values for form are ‘NFC’, ‘NFKC’, ‘NFD’, and ‘NFKD’. If you wana more about NFKD go to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682397/can-somone-explain-how-unicodedata-normalizeform-unistr-work-with-examples#)

```
In [12]: u = unichr(40960) + u'abcd' + unichr(1972)
In [13]: u.encode('utf-8')
Out[13]: '\xea\x80\x80abcd\xde\xb4'
In [14]: u
Out[14]: u'\ua000abcd\u07b4'
In [16]: u.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
Out[16]: 'abcd'
```

From the above code you will get what `encode('ascii','ignore')`  does.

Ref : https://docs.python.org/2/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize

Comment: data={ "text":"RT @peddoc63: Looks like Trump's anti-establishment and self-funding days are over. Well that took less than 12 hours\ud83d\ude44 https:\/\/t.co\/W7zaUK8\u2026" }

Above is a sample.

When i do out_text = normalize('NFKD', data).encode('ascii','ignore')

It gives me error 'ascii' codec can't encode characters in position 119-120

Comment: @ashish1512: why are you passing a whole dictionary into `normalize()`?

Comment: It's not exactly a dictionary. When i do print type(data), it gives me <type 'unicode'>

Comment: @RahulKP: please do *explain* what the code does. You are not sticking to the letter of the question here; it is nice that your method retains letters without accents, etc. but the OP simply asked to remove any non-ASCII codepoint.

Comment: @ashish1512: that isn't clear from your comment. You appear to have **undecoded JSON** in that case. In undecoded JSON, `\uhhhh` escape sequences are **not Unicode codepoints** (*yet*). Decode your JSON to Python first.

Comment: @ashish1512 try `data['text']` instead of `data`.