# How to get rid of some characters from string? .replace() doesn't work

Tags: python, xml, replace, xml.etree

I need to get rid of polish characters from string I got from xml file. I use .replace() but in this case it doesn't work. Why?
The code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8
from prestapyt import PrestaShopWebService
from xml.etree import ElementTree

prestashop = PrestaShopWebService('http://localhost/prestashop/api', 
                              'key')
prestashop.debug = True

name = ElementTree.tostring(prestashop.search('products', options=
{'display': '[name]', 'filter[id]': '[2]'}), encoding='cp852',  
method='text')

print name
print name.replace('ł', 'l')
```

Output:

```
Naturalne mydło odświeżające
Naturalne mydło odświeżające
```

But when I try to replace non polish character it works fine.

```
print name
print name.replace('a', 'o')
```

Result:

```
Naturalne mydło odświeżające
Noturolne mydło odświeżojące
```

This also work's fine:

```
name = "Naturalne mydło odświeżające"
print name.replace('ł', 'l')
```

Any advise?

Comment: You need to normalize the Unicode form of both strings to the same [normal form](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_equivalence).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can somone explain how unicodedata.normalize(form, unistr) work with examples?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682397/can-somone-explain-how-unicodedata-normalizeform-unistr-work-with-examples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing encodings with your byte strings.  Here's a short working example reproducing the issue.  I assume you are running in a Windows console that defaults to an encoding of `cp852`:

```
#!python2
# coding: utf-8
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
name_element = et.Element('data')
name_element.text = u'Naturalne mydło odświeżające'
name = et.tostring(name_element,encoding='cp852', method='text')
print name
print name.replace('ł', 'l')
```

Output (no replacement):

```
Naturalne mydło odświeżające
Naturalne mydło odświeżające
```

The reason is, the `name` string was encoded in `cp852` but the byte string constant `'ł'` is encoded in the source code encoding of `utf-8`.

```
print repr(name)
print repr('ł')
```

Output:

```
'Naturalne myd\x88o od\x98wie\xbeaj\xa5ce'
'\xc5\x82'
```

The best solution is to use Unicode strings:

```
#!python2
# coding: utf-8
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
name_element = et.Element('data')
name_element.text = u'Naturalne mydło odświeżające'
name = et.tostring(name_element,encoding='cp852', method='text').decode('cp852')
print name
print name.replace(u'ł', u'l')
print repr(name)
print repr(u'ł')
```

Output (replacement was made):

```
Naturalne mydło odświeżające
Naturalne mydlo odświeżające
u'Naturalne myd\u0142o od\u015bwie\u017caj\u0105ce'
u'\u0142'
```

Note that Python 3's `et.tostring` has a Unicode option, and string constants are Unicode by default.  The `repr()` version of the string is more readable as well, but `ascii()` implements the old behavior.  You'll also find that Python 3.6 will print Polish even to consoles not using a Polish code page, so maybe you wouldn't need to replace the characters at all.

```
#!python3
# coding: utf-8
from xml.etree import ElementTree as et
name_element = et.Element('data')
name_element.text = 'Naturalne mydło odświeżające'
name = et.tostring(name_element,encoding='unicode', method='text')
print(name)
print(name.replace('ł','l'))
print(repr(name),repr('ł'))
print(ascii(name),ascii('ł'))
```

Output:

```
Naturalne mydło odświeżające
Naturalne mydlo odświeżające
'Naturalne mydło odświeżające' 'ł'
'Naturalne myd\u0142o od\u015bwie\u017caj\u0105ce' '\u0142'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Encode/decode thing is still a bit tricky to me, so i guess I would have to study Unicode Howto. I will also consider moving to python 3.x.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your problem correctly, you can use [`unidecode`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode):

```
>>> from unidecode import unidecode
>>> unidecode("Naturalne mydło odświeżające")
'Naturalne mydlo odswiezajace'
```

You might have to decode your cp852 encoded string with `name.decode('utf_8')` first.

Comment: Thanks! I've implemented your sugestion and now everything work's fine.