# How to fix : TypeError: normalize() argument 2 must be str, not list

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I'm making an api call that pulls the desired endpoints from ...url/articles.json and transforms it into a csv file. My problem here is that the ['labels_name'] endpoint is a string with multiple values.(an article might have multiple labels)
How can I pull multiple values of a string without getting this error . `"File "articles_labels.py", line 40, in <module>
    decode_3 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', article_label)
TypeError: normalize() argument 2 must be str, not list"`?

```
import requests
import csv
import unicodedata
import getpass

url = 'https://......./articles.json'
user = ' '
pwd = ' '
csvfile = 'articles_labels.csv'

output_1 = []
output_1.append("id")
output_2 = []
output_2.append("title")
output_3 = []
output_3.append("label_names")
output_4 = []
output_4.append("link")

while url:
    response = requests.get(url, auth=(user, pwd))
    data = response.json()
    for article in data['articles']:
        article_id = article['id']
        decode_1 = int(article_id)
        output_1.append(decode_1)

    for article in data['articles']:
        title = article['title']
        decode_2 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', title)
        output_2.append(decode_2)

    for article in data['articles']:
        article_label = article['label_names']
        decode_3 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', article_label)
        output_3.append(decode_3) 

    for article in data['articles']:
        article_url = article['html_url']
        decode_3 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', article_url)
        output_3.append(decode_3)

    print(data['next_page'])
    url = data['next_page']

print("Number of articles:")
print(len(output_1))   

with open(csvfile, 'w') as fp:
    writer = csv.writer(fp,dialect = 'excel')
    writer.writerows([output_1])
    writer.writerows([output_2])
    writer.writerows([output_3])
    writer.writerows([output_4])
```

Comment: The error message means that `title` is a list, not a string, when you pass it in to the `unicodedate.normalize()` function. Could you try to print out what `title` is at this point?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "articles_labels.py", line 40, in <module>
    decode_3 = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', article_label)
TypeError: normalize() argument 2 must be str, not list

Comment: title is a string and it prints when I run it.. the only problem is with the label_names that is according to the documentation also a string.. but in this case it has multiple values.. as I said..in my case.. an article might have multiple labels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My problem here is that the ['labels_name'] endpoint is a string with multiple values.(an article might have multiple labels) How can I pull multiple values of a string

It's a list not a string, so you don't have "a string with multiple values" you have a list of multiple strings, already, as-is.

The question is what you want to do with them, CSV certainly isn't going to handle that, so you must decide on a way to serialise a list of strings to a single string e.g. by joining them together (with some separator like space or comma) or by just picking the first one (beware to handle the case where there is none), … either way the issue is not really technical.

Comment: hey .. thank you for your answer.. i've just passed list() instead of unicodedata.normalize () and it worked.. for those articles that don't have labels I just get empty brackets.

Answer (score 0):

[unicodedata.normalize](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unicodedata.html#unicodedata.normalize) takes a unicode string, and not a list as the error says. The correct way to use `unicodedata.normalize` will be (example taken from [How does unicodedata.normalize(form, unistr) work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14682397/how-does-unicodedata-normalizeform-unistr-work)

```
from unicodedata import normalize

print(normalize('NFD', u'\u00C7'))
print(normalize('NFC', u'C\u0327'))
#Ç
#Ç
```

Hence you need to make sure that `unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', title)` has title as a unicode string